# foreman fails to load environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, foreman

I'm using rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.0.0

When I start the server with foreman **some** of the environment variables fail to load. It really bugs me that some of the variables are loaded.

```
foreman start -e development.env
```

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec passenger start -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV
```

development.env file

```
S3_BUCKET=bucketname
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=accesskey
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secretaccesskey
RAILS_ENV=development
PORT=3000
```

In my application.rb file i've added some logging to help debug this problem

```
puts "PORT is #{ENV["PORT"].inspect}"
puts "RAILS_ENV is #{ENV["RAILS_ENV"].inspect}"
puts "S3_BUCKET is #{ENV["S3_BUCKET"].inspect}"
puts "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID is #{ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"].inspect}"
puts "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY is #{ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"].inspect}"
```

Once I start the server this is the output for the logging code

```
23:34:52 worker.1 | PORT is nil
23:34:52 worker.1 | RAILS_ENV is "development"
23:34:52 worker.1 | S3_BUCKET is nil
23:34:52 worker.1 | AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID is nil
23:34:52 worker.1 | AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY is nil
```

Why oh Why ? :-(

When I load the rails console with foreman it successfully loads the variables

```
foreman run -e development.env rails c
```

Comment: The logging output youve shown is from the worker process, does the web process see the environment variables, like rails console does?

Comment: I don't think any of your values from development.env are being used. Rails itself sets the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable to 'development' if it isn't set already. You could verify this by trying to set `RAILS_ENV` to a different value.

Answer (score 1):

Try modify your `development.env` like

```
export S3_BUCKET=bucketname
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=accesskey
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secretaccesskey
export RAILS_ENV=development
export PORT=3000
```

Then in the terminal

```
$ source /path/to/development.env
$ foreman start
```

### Advanced

You can use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) to manage some of your environment variables without polluting your system environment. Though it can't manage those environment variables required for server booting like `PORT`.